# when executing this code i got segmentation fault core dumped

Tags: c

I am getting error: segmentation fault core dumped.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
char *strcpy(char *s,char *t)
{
  char *ptr = s;
  while((*s = *t) != '\0')
    s++;
  t++;
  return ptr;
}
int main()
{
  char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);
  char *t;
  scanf("%s",t);
  printf("%s",strcpy(s,t));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you please first learn to format your question properly? [How to format your code properly in OS](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). It's really NOT easy to read your question.

Comment: t does not have a valid location

Comment: After introducing proper formatting: Are you aware that `t++` is not covered by `while()`?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. If the question is "how do you debug a segmentation fault", you should tell us a bit about what kind of debugger you are going to use or what techniques you wish to learn because there are many ways to do it.

Comment: When using a pointer, always answer the question "What valid memory is my pointer pointing to?" before attempting to use it. Here `t` is an *uninitialized pointer* that points (nowhere) when used with `scanf`.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting segmentation fault because you are using `char` pointer `t` before allocating memory to it for getting input from user:

```
  char *t;
  scanf("%s",t); // using t before allocating memory
```

Allocate memory before using it:

```
char *t = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);
if (NULL == t) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Failed to allocate memory");  
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The other problem is in function `strcpy()` function `while` loop:

```
  while((*s = *t) != '\0')
     s++;
```

You have not given the parenthesis in loop body so only the vary next statement is consider as loop body and every iteration of this loop will only increase the pointer `s` and the pointer `t` will keep on pointing to first character of string. At one moment of time the increment in pointer `s` (`s++`) in every iteration of `while` loop will make `s` accessing the memory beyond the allocated memory which is an undefined behavior and you may get segmentation fault. Instead you should do:

```
  while((*s = *t) != '\0') {
      s++;
      t++;
  }
```

Which is equivalent to

```
  while(*s++ = *t++)
  ;
```

Reason is - the post increment operator increase the value of operand by 1 but *[which is a pointer in this case]* the value of the expression is the operand's original value prior to the increment operation. So in expression `*s++` and `*t++`, the pointer `s` and `t` moves to the next position but returns the old content. The expression `(*s++ = *t++)` when assigning the null terminating character `\0`, the expression will result in `\0` which is equivalent to `0` and the loop will terminate.

Also, make sure to free the dynamically allocated memory once you are done with it. So, after calling your string copy function you should:

```
free(t);
free(s);
```

You can also use the `char` array instead of dynamically allocating memory, like this:

```
char s[50];
char t[50];
```

With this you don't need to take care of allocating and freeing the memory.

Giving the function name same as the standard library function name is not a good practice. Better to give name like - `mystrcpy`.

Also, while copying string we only read the source string so make the source string parameter `const` like this:

```
char *mystrcpy (char *s, const char *t);
                         ^^^^^
```

Avoid using single character variable names like you have used in your program - `s` and `t`. Follow good programming practice, always give name which indicate some meaning like the parameters name in your string copy function, instead of `s` you can give `destination` and instead of `t` you can give `source`.

Comment: #include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
char *strcpy(char *s,char *t)
{
  char *ptr = s;
  while((*s = *t) != '\0')
  {s++;
  t++;}
  return ptr;
}
int main()
{
  char *s = "Hello";
char *t = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);
if (NULL == t) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Failed to allocate memory");  
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
  printf("%s",strcpy(s,t));
  return 0;
}